# AngularJS : UI Router conditional based on authentification

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm using Devise for authenticatication in my Rails and Angular app. I'm trying to do a conditional statement on one of the states based on whether a user is authenticated.

I'm using the onEnter callback function to determine if a user is authenticated.

routes:

```
// Dashboard state
.state('dashboard', {
  url: '/dashboard',
  templateUrl: 'dashboard.html',
  controller: 'MainCtrl',
})

// Login state
.state('login', {
  url: '/login',
  templateUrl: '_login.html',
  controller: 'AuthCtrl',
  onEnter: ['$state', 'Auth', function($state, Auth) {
    Auth.currentUser().then(function (){
      $state.go('dashboard');
    })
  }]
})

// Register state
.state('register', {
  url: '/register',
  templateUrl: '_register.html',
  controller: 'AuthCtrl',
  onEnter: ['$state', 'Auth', function($state, Auth) {
    Auth.currentUser().then(function (){
      $state.go('dashboard');
    })
  }]
})

$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('dashboard');
```

Nav controller

```
// NAV controller
// ------------------------------
.controller('NavCtrl', ['$scope', 'Auth',

    // Main scope (used in views)
    function($scope, Auth) {

        $scope.signedIn = Auth.isAuthenticated;
        $scope.logout = Auth.logout;

        Auth.currentUser().then(function (user){
            $scope.user = user;
        });

        $scope.$on('devise:new-registration', function (e, user){
            $scope.user = user;
        });

        $scope.$on('devise:login', function (e, user){
            $scope.user = user;
        });

        $scope.$on('devise:logout', function (e, user){
            $scope.user = {};
        });
    }

])
```

Authentification controller

```
// Authentification controller
// ------------------------------
.controller('AuthCtrl', ['$scope', '$state', 'Auth',

// Main scope (used in views)
function($scope, $state, Auth) {

    $scope.login = function() {
        Auth.login($scope.user).then(function(){
          $state.go('home');
        });
    };

    $scope.register = function() {
        Auth.register($scope.user).then(function(){
          $state.go('home');
        });
    };

}

]);
```

How can I determine a non-authenticated user on the dashboard state, and redirect them to login?

Answer (score 0):

You have have a few options to go down for this sort of thing:

1) In MainCtrl add an init() function which checks `if(!Auth.isAuthenticated) $state.go('login')`. Downside is if they lose auth after the controller is instantiated this does not redirect them.

2) I presume you're making some kind of back-end calls which require Authentication. If so, if they're not authed you can catch the 401 response via an http interceptor and redirect them to login there. This is the method I always use.

3) Attach a $watch to Auth.isAuthenticated do the redirect from there